# Sas date format concatenating

Tags: sas

I have two datatset Input12 and input18. Below is the code.

New12 dataset have variable score_date in format yymmn6.

```
   data new12;
   set input12;
   run;
```

Now adding new variable score_date in dataset new18

```
%let score_date=201807;
data new18;
set input18;
format score_date yymmn6.;
run;
```

After concatenating the dataset new 12 and new18 the date format is not in yymmn6.

```
 data new;
 set new12 new18;
 run;
```

This is giving informat date for new12 and blank for new18 in new

```
 data new;
 set new18 new12;
 run;
```

This is giving correct date format for new18 and blank for new12 in new.

Is there any reason for improper format after concatenating.

Comment: Please show your concatenation code. Order within the set statement matters and will dictate a column's format.

Comment: data new;
 set new12 new18;
 run;
This is giving informat date for new12 and blank for new18 in new

 data new;
 set new18 new12;
 run; 
This is giving correct date format for new18 and blank for new12 in new.

Comment: Why the macro variable `score_date` containing a date representation.  You never resolve as `&score_date`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the source data sets for a variable's format, place a `format` statement in your data set stacking (concatenation) DATA step.

Example:

```
  data new;
    set 
      new12
      new18
    ;

    format score_date yymmn6.;
```

If you mean to have your date representation stored in a macro symbol, as I *infer* from your posted code, you need to `input` the representation using the appropriate **informat** in order to get a SAS date value.

```
   score_date = input ("&score_date", yymmn6.);
   format score_date yymmn6.;
```

An alternative is to set the macro symbol to the source code of a SAS date literal.

```
%let score_date = "01JUL2018"D;
```

and resolve that later in DATA Step as perhaps

```
 data new18; 
   score_date = &score_date;
   format score_date yymmn6.;
 run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below codes.

```
  %let score_date="01dec2019"d;
  data twelvenew;
  set twelve;
  score_date=&scoredate.;
  format score_date yymmn6.;
  run;

  %let score_date="01jun2019"d;
  data eightnew;
  set eight;
  score_date=&scoredate.;
  format score_date yymmn6.;
  run;

 data final;
 set eightnew twelvenew;
 run;
```

I am getting dates only eightnew in final dataset and others are missing.

Is iam missing anything here.